# Kafka lag exporter Docker container restarting after update

Tags: docker, containers

Have run the docker image (v0.7.0)  from "https://github.com/seglo/kafka-lag-exporter" to scrape the metrics. It was working fine. Then tried to upgraded the ver to 0.8.0 (with restart as unless stopped). Now the container is restarting again and again. Have removed all the images and containers, still the container is restarting. Tried to rollback to the previous version, but still the container is restarting.

What should be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

from logs, understand that somehow the container was not able to read the application.conf file. Deleted and recreated the file makes it working again. Below is the logs.

> Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$IO: /opt/docker/conf/application.conf: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/docker/conf/application.conf (No such file or directory)